# Force update when PPA repository doesn't have release file

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I have a PPA installed which does NOT have a release file for my 21.04 system. Currently, the outdated PPA is stalling anything else from updating. I would like to keep the PPA enabled, but have all other updates and upgrades pass through. Is this possible?

EDIT: 'upup' is just an alias for "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade"

[image]

Comment: It doesn't have a release file because it doesn't support that release.  By forcing it you risk making your system *unstable* and having applications *segfault* etc due to mismatch of API/ABI's or just ending up in *dep hell*.  The error is there for a reason (telling you to fix it).   If you need to use a package from it; it's far safer to do your manual checks for that package, then manually add it in my opinion (not leaving it present for future problems to occur)

Comment: @guiverc not exactly, I'm looking to keep it active (without installing the software) and have it throw the error but update/upgrade all OTHER packages! this was I will know when the release is out (the error will disappear) without having to check github periodically, but it won't affect my system in the meantime. Is something like this possible?

Comment: *without having to check github periodically* -- You can request the maintainer of the PPA to package it for 21.04 (if all the dependencies are satisfied, it is only a matter of a few clicks to create the package from the existing ones).

Comment: It looks you just want `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`  - `;` instead of `&&` so that when `apt update` fails it still runs `apt upgrade`.

Comment: @muru That should be the answer rather than a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

[SysMonTask Installation](https://github.com/KrispyCamel4u/SysMonTask)

[image]

start the terminal and then

```
wget https://github.com/KrispyCamel4u/SysMonTask/releases/download/v1.3.9/sysmontask_1.3.9-ubuntu20.10_all.deb
```

or

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~camel-neeraj/+archive/ubuntu/sysmontask/+files/sysmontask_1.3.9-ubuntu20.10-a_all.deb

sudo apt install ./sysmontask_1.3.9-ubuntu20.10_all.deb
```

or
sudo apt install ./sysmontask_1.3.9-ubuntu20.10-a_all.deb